# JavaScript - why must we return a function from a self-invoking function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code has a runtime error:

```
var person = (function(){

    var Person = {

        init: function() {

        },
    };

    return new Person();

    /*return function(){
        new Person();
    }*/

})();

console.log(person);
```

it says I have to return a function instead of a plain Object.

Why is that I can't return an object from the self-invoking/anonymous outer function? Why must I return a function?

likewise, this altered code also gives me a similar error:

```
var person = function(){

    var Person = {

        init: function() {

        },

    };

    return new Person();

    /*return function(){
     new Person();
     }*/

};

console.log(person());
```

Comment: *"it says I have to return a function instead of a plain Object."* ***"It" what?***

Comment: node.js runtime console output says. my bad, I hate pronouns too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is that I can't return an object from the self-invoking/anonymous outer function?

You *can* return an object, that is not what's wrong with your code.

The problem with your code is that `Person` is an object, not a function. Calling `new Person()` is invalid.

```js
var person = (function () {
    return {
      name: 'bob'
    };
}());
console.log(person.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have declared `Person` as an object, and you can't use `new Person()` with an object. To create a "class" in ES5 you create a function instead.

```
var person = (function(){
    var Person = function() {
        this.init = function() {
            console.log('Initing!')
        }
    };

    return new Person();
})();

console.log(person);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/758zL8v3/

Answer (score 1):

> *Why must I return a function?*

Because the `new` operator creates an instance of a *Javascript Object*. And to create it, it needs a **constructor function**.  And that is that function you're asking about.

It's almost like calling a typical function

```
function add() {
  return 1 + 1;
}

add();
// 2
```

but when you call it with the `new` operator, you create a new instance of this function object (functions are objects too, in Javascript).

```
function myAdder() {
  this.a = 1;
  this.b = 1;
  this.add = function () {
    return this.a + this.b;
  };

  return this;
}

myObject = new myAdder();
myObject.b = 2;
myObject.add();
// 3
```

And the object notation of `myAdder` would be:

```
function myAdder() {
  return {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
    add: function () {
      return this.a + this.b;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *alternative* is the following Object constructor:

```
var person = function(){

    var Person = function(){

        this.init = function() {

        };

    };

    return new Person();

};
```

You can read more about Object Oriented programming [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: yeah, that's what I am looking for